# Get all entities that implement interface

Tags: entity-framework

I have several entities that implement IModel interface. I want to get records from all tables whose entities implement this interface. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
context.ObjectStateManager
       .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added /* All states here */)
       .Select(e => e.Entity)
       .OfType<IModel>()
       .ToList();
```